# How add id with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a file xml and i want convert that to html & i want add ID to my tag html with value of tags for example :

```
<Root>
    <row>
        <WID>10</WID>
        <word>Bob</word>
        <SID>1</SID>
        <Ah>1</Ah>
        <Je>1</Je>
        <Hb>1</Hb>
        <ParentID>4556</ParentID>
        <Page>1</Page>
        <Joint>1</Joint>
        <SName>Stive</SName>
    </row>
    <row>
        <WID>5941</WID>
        <word>Jany</word>
        <SID>2</SID>
        <Ah>74</Ah>
        <Je>1</Je>
        <Hb>1</Hb>
        <ParentID>2461</ParentID>
        <Page>11</Page>
        <Joint>10</Joint>
        <SName>Jessy</SName>
    </row>
    .
    .
    .
    <row>
        <WID>14295</WID>
        <word>James</word>
        <SID>5</SID>
        <Ah>113</Ah>
        <Joze>7</Joze>
        <Hb>13</Hb>
        <ParentID>3066</ParentID>
        <Page>126</Page>
        <Joint>98</Joint>
        <SName>JIM</SName>
    </row>
</Root>
```

and i want convert to :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span id="1-1">
            <span calss="test">
                Bob
            </span>
            <span calss="number">
                1
            </span>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

please notice to IDs span the first number [1-1] is SID and second number is Ah.
Thanks.

Comment: Note that this site is not meant to be the one where you come to post your assignments and have other people do them for you. Please show your own efforts so far and explain where you're stuck. This includes posting a sample of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How add id with XSLT

Something like the following should do:

```
<span id="{SID}-{Ah}">
```

If your context is row.

Comment: Hi hr_117. how i can distinct SID & Ah?

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="//row" group-by="Ah">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Ah"/>,
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>